# IOS 6 in navigation, how can I set a screen to not highlight a tab?

Tags: iphone, ios6, tabs, navigation, highlight

Please help! Our IOS app has 4 navigation tabs at the bottom, in which only a couple screens on the app do not need to be highlighted.

How can we not display a highlighted tab on particular screens for IOS 6?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is reall vague and it's hard to understand what is going on. Please provide more detailed information, code, screenshot etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using "Custom TabBar" development.

In that, you can set bottom tabbar button manually, with selected and deselected images.

You can create one sample function in which, all bottom tabbar button has deselected images, and call that function from your screen where you want it to be not highlighted.

Hope you got an idea.

Happy Coding!

Cheers!